Using complex phases to do linear regression
The following is non-standard but was interested to see if there is value in following this path.
Consider a linear regression problem without intercept, so simply, $y=ax$ and some data is provided $(y_k, x_k)$. We can simply follow the MSE path and get the usual formula for $a$. But lets say we explore the complex numbers $z_k = e^{ i t (y_k - a x_k)}$ then we have
$$\gamma(t,a) = \sum_k z_k=\sum_k e^{ i t (y_k - a x_k)}$$
Now, if $a$ is the optimal one $\gamma(t,a)$ will have high magnitude for longer time, $t$. The intuition is that if the differences in the phase of each $x_k$ are large then as time progresses $|\gamma(a,t)|$ will decay very fast (given they are aligned at t=0).
Is there a way to find optimal $a$ using $\gamma(t,a)$?
My attempt: The closest thing I can find is to consider the joint characteristic function;
$$\sum_k e^{it_1 y_k + t_2 x_k} = \sum_k e^{it_1 a x_k + t_2 x_k} $$
$$\sum_k e^{it_1 y_k + t_2 x_k} = \sum_k e^{i x_k(t_1 a + t_2)}$$
If you take the derivative with respect to $t_1$ and $t_2$ and set them both to zero and then solve for $a$, you get the usual answer. But this isn't quite the same intuition as above as it involves two times.
